# Como añado datos a mi sql desde un CSV?

Tags: python, sql, csv

Tengo un csv de la siguiente manera

```
no_orden    codigo_producto cantidad_orden  precio_cada nombre_producto linea_productos descr   precio_compra   fecha_orden no_cliente  nombre_cliente  tlf direccion   ciudad  estado  codigo_postal   pais
0   10100   S18_1749    30  136.00  1917 Grand Touring Sedan    Vintage Cars    Our Vintage Car models realistically portray a...   86.70   2003-01-06  363 Online Diecast Creations Co.    6035558647  2304 Long Airport Avenue    Nashua  NH  62005   USA
1   10100   S18_2248    50  55.09   1911 Ford Town Car  Vintage Cars    Our Vintage Car models realistically portray a...   33.30   2003-01-06  363 Online Diecast Creations Co.    6035558647  2304 Long Airport Avenue    Nashua  NH  62005   USA
```

tiene 17 columnas en total

asi que con este csv lo he transformado en un dataframe asi:

```
import pandas as pd

concesionario = pd.read_csv("Coches/ventas.csv")

df = pd.DataFrame(concesionario)
```

y luego de crear la siguiente tabla en SQL:

```
cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE Pedido
(no_orden INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
codigo_producto CHAR(20), 
cantidad_orden INT NOT NULL, 
precio_cada FLOAT (10), 
nombre_producto TEXT NOT NULL, 
linea_productos TEXT NOT NULL, 
descr TEXT NOT NULL, 
precio_compra FLOAT (10), 
fecha_orden DATE, 
no_cliente INT NOT NULL)

''')
```

y funciona, pero ahora quiero rellenar dicha tabla nueva

Para rellenar con el contenido del CSV he intentado este codigo:

```
for index,row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO Pedido (no_orden, codigo_producto, cantidad_orden, precio_cada, nombre_producto, linea_productos, descr, precio_compra, fecha_orden, no_cliente)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                ''', 
                row.no_orden,
                row.codigo_producto, 
                row.cantidad_orden,
                row.precio_cada,
                row.nombre_producto,
                row.linea_productos,
                row.descr,
                row.precio_compra,
                row.fecha_orden,
                row.no_cliente 
        
                )
conn.commit()
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Otro intento es:

```
  import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import io

file = io.StringIO("1,2,3\n4,5,6")

db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, names=("col1", "col2", "col3"))

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE df(col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 INT)")

# Pasamos a itertuples index=False para que no quede el indice incluido en la tupla
for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO df(col1,col2,col3) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", row)

db.commit()

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM df")

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

y me da el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'method' is not iterable
```

Creo que es por mala interpretación

Tal vez hay otra manera de hacerlo o se puede corregir mi codigo, desconozco el error.

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

#### Explicación

La causa del error es muy simple. El método itertuples del objeto Dataframe devuelve un iterable de [NamedTuples](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) con el index del dataframe y los valores de la fila. Y al hacer `index, row` estás tratando de desempaquetar una namedtuple de, supuestamente, 2 items. Pero como dicha namedtuple tiene más de dos items, Python te lo avisa con ese error.
Por las dudas lo repito, la NamedTuple devuelta incluye, por default, el indice de la fila en el dataframe.

Nota adicional: Recuerda que iterar sobre un dataframe debe ser un plan de ultimo recurso, ya que Pandas tiene métodos muchisimo más rapidos implementados en C (el lenguaje sobre el que está programado Python).

Sin embargo, te ofresco un par de alternativas a tu código (aunque, en realidad, la segunda alternativa es basicamente tu código original con el error solucionado y una mejora).

#### Alternativa 1: Dataframe.to_sql

Pandas ofrece un método llamado [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), que hace por nosotros el trabajo de pasar el Dataframe a sql. Pero antes de que pienses "la mejor solución es esta", te advierto que, sin tener un módulo de terceros llamado sqlalchemy (que por cierto, es muy bueno, lo recomiendo), solo es compatible con sqlite3.

Hay que aclarar explicitamente a Pandas que no trate al indice como una columna más de la tabla pasando `index=False` a to_sql.

A continuación, dejo el código de prueba hecho con sqlite3

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import io

# este es un archivo csv cargado en memoria
file = io.StringIO("1,2,3\n4,5,6")

db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, names=("col1", "col2", "col3"))
df.to_sql("df", db, index=False)

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM df")

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

#### Alternativa 2: Hacerlo "manualmente"

También podes hacerlo "manualmente", pero requerirá que iteres sobre el dataframe, lo que significa que será más lento. Por cierto, row es, en el fondo, una tupla modificada, no necesitas acceder a cada valor uno por uno si pones las columnas en el orden correcto en la consulta.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import io

file = io.StringIO("1,2,3\n4,5,6")

db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, names=("col1", "col2", "col3"))

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE df(col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 INT)")

# Pasamos a itertuples index=False para que no quede el indice incluido en la tupla
for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO df(col1,col2,col3) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", row)

db.commit()

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM df")

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

Nota: Si querés, podés crear una función que construya una consulta a partir de los datos de un Dataframe y hacer una versión más general de esta alternativa. Pero si lo haces procura evitar hacer posible la [inyección sql](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL) (Código malicioso que altera el funcionamiento de tu consulta). Usa siempre que sea posible parametros.

#### edit: aclarando cosas

io.StringIO sirve para emular un archivo de texto. Si lo que quieres es cargar un archivo de verdad, debes hacer `open("elcsv.csv", "r")` y cerrar el archivo cuando sea necesario... o, dejar que pandas haga ese trabajo por vos y hacer `pd.read_csv("elcsv.csv"...`.

Por otro lado, ten en cuenta que cuando le pasas la cadena ":memory:" a sqlite3.connect, lo que hace es crear la base de datos en memoria (es decir, no la almacena en ningun archivo)

Comment: hola buenas, primero gracias por tan elaborada respuesta. actualice el post con el código y me da error, pero en este caso creo que es por haber interpretado mal tu código Gracias

Comment: es que no entiendo con que te refieres con el  "file = io.StringIO("1,2,3\n4,5,6")

db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")". es decir, que es el 1,2,3... y el :memory:. Ademas el "file" habría que cambiarlo por el nombre de mi csv entiendo no?

Comment: Perdon, no lo explique. StringIO acepta una cadena inicial y, con ella, "emula" un archivo de texto abierto por la funcion open. En realidad, el 1,2,3 no signica nada especial. Simplemente es un csv de prueba con las filas 1,2,3 y 4,5,6. Y finalmente, el :memory: significa "crea la base de datos en memoria, no la almacenes en ningun archivo".

Comment: La variable file debe de ser un objeto que represente un archivo de texto.

Comment: Oh, no vi el primer comentario, sorry. De nada! Ahora reviso el nuevo error.

Comment: vale gracias :)

Comment: De nada c: ya edite la respuesta dando aclaraciones adicionales! Espero que te sirvan!

Comment: ahora lo entiendo mejor, acabo de cambiar el código pero ahora me da otro error. te pongo mas información en el código por si t sirve.

Comment: Que raro... A mi no me da error el código publicado. Seguro que el código publicado y el que produce el error es el mismo?